# Do I need to rebuild after updating POM file before running unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, pom.xml

I know IntelliJ IDEA will execute `import changes` after changing pom file and recompile the whole project before running a unit test, I wonder if eclipse also has this process or it requires me to rebuild the whole module using `mvn clean install` after I change my pom file?

Comment: It depends.  How are you executing the unit tests?

Comment: Does it work if you don't do `mvn clean install`? If so, the answer is "no, you don't need to". Else, the answer is "yes, you need to". Simple. (And this check works regardless of whatever method you use to execute your unit tests - clearly, you're not using maven to execute the unit tests, else you wouldn't need to ask the question)

Comment: @Stephen C by clicking run as Junit test in eclipse

Comment: I would recommend doing a Eclipse project clean ... if there Eclipse appears not to have rebuilt following the POM file change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"mvn clean install" places the resources defined in your pom file in your local maven repository. But IDE's like netbeans, eclipse or intelliJ will load them in them for you in the background and the needed jar files will be placed in the folders needed during the execution of your unit test.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your development environment. Some editors, like Eclipse might load them in the background for you silently, if they are placed in the correct resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

mvn install is your jar package installed in your local library, generally not set in the user directory below. M2 \ below.
So you want to test, need to be implemented "mvn clean install"